# Query to exclude (doesn't contain) certain values from elastic

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST query to filter records from elastic.

Following query will filter records based on `articleIds` list. It works fine.

```
QueryContainer nestedQuery = null;
nestedQuery &= Query<PublishedArticle>.Terms(qs => qs
               .Field(f => f.AssignedArticleList.FirstOrDefault().AssignedArticleId)
                  .Terms(articleIds)
              );
```

But now I want to fetch records which doesn't contain values in prop `articleIds`. How do I achieve this? Was checking elastic [documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) on `must_not` clause. How do I build this query?

`articleIds` is basically a list of integers.

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `bool` query with a `must_not` clause

```
var articleIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

client.Search<PublishedArticle>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .MustNot(mn => mn
                .Terms(t => t
                    .Field(f => f.AssignedArticleList.FirstOrDefault().AssignedArticleId)
                    .Terms(articleIds)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Using the `!` operator, a `must_not` can be shortened in NEST using operator overloading to

```
client.Search<PublishedArticle>(s => s
    .Query(q => !q
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.AssignedArticleList.FirstOrDefault().AssignedArticleId)
            .Terms(articleIds)
        )
    )
);
```

Both produce

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "assignedArticleList.assignedArticleId": [
              1,
              2,
              3,
              4
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. worked perfectly fine! :) Is there any tutorials reference other then whats mentioned in elastic documentation?

Comment: There is the client documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html which we are looking to expand further to include additional sections on analysis, indexing, percolation, etc. as well as better organize the sections there.